# jQuery get each form input that got a parrent div with the right class

Tags: jquery, css

on a simple form like this:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="success">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
</div>
<div class="notsuccess">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

is it possible with jQuery to get a list or array of each input that has a parrent div with a class of success ?
i want to make some kind of validation.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reading it literally

> (1) a list or array of each input
>
> (2) that has a *parent div with a class of success

Then `$('div.success input')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$("input").parent("div.success").each(function() {
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`var $elements = $('input').parent('.success');`

To iterate over them all you could use:

```
$('input').parent('.success').each( function(i, ele) { 
    $(this); // This is each .success element.
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input', $('div.success'))
```

By far the simplest answer. Remember, the $() selector will create a jQuery object by default with all DOM nodes that match the selection. That means you don't have to create an array, it's already been done.